# Centering a child within a parent on a responsive flowing website wireframe

Tags: css, html, center

I am currently trying to build a responsive mobile website.
The second level div in the code below is not picking up the 100% width from it's parent div (which should be the maximum width of the device).

The child div needs to sit centered within the parent div on the device

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; background:#0FF;">
    <div style="max-width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; ">

        <a href="http://website.com.au/contact.html" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image21','','images/make-an-enquiry-icon-2.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()">
            <img src="images/make-an-enquiry-icon-1.png" alt="" name="Image21" max-width="100%" border="0" id="Image21" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; align:center;" />
        </a>
        <div align="center" style="width:100%;">
        <a href="https://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp" target="_blank" class="style41" style="text-align:left"><img src="images/add-plus-icon.png" width="14" height="9" border="0" />
            View Larger Map
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please Note: The title may be incorrect if you are using American English. I use British English as I am located in Australia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working, you might have something else going on in your other CSS.

Check this out.  Same code as yours, i added a border to the inner div so it can be seen.

http://jsfiddle.net/LAfaR/

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; background:#0FF;">
    <div style="max-width:200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:solid 1px black ">

        <a href="http://boxhillindoorsports.com.au/contact.html" target="_blank" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image21','','images/make-an-enquiry-icon-2.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()">
            <img src="images/make-an-enquiry-icon-1.png" alt="" name="Image21" max-width="100%" border="0" id="Image21" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; align:center;" />
        </a>
        <div align="center" style="width:100%;">
        <a href="https://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=ll=-37.833988,145.132484&amp;spn=0.017761,0.045748&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" target="_blank" class="style41" style="text-align:left"><img src="images/add-plus-icon.png" width="14" height="9" border="0" />
            View Larger Map
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Still having a similar problem to before as the div ends up half on the mobile screen and half off. It seems as though the parent div is 200% width and the margin flow that should center this is pushing it off

Comment: You may be better off using a grid system or Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.org).  That stuff you're trying to do is very, very tricky.  You'll get it just right on one phone and it won't work on another.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks :) Sadly, I am adapting some-one else's pre-existing table designed website and making it `more` responsive

Comment: That was why i recommended them.  When you get tired of beating yourself over the head, maybe you'll take some good advice.